# downloading file in WPF Task; losing and restoring internet connection

Tags: c#, wpf, task

In WPF I'm using `Task.Run` from the main thread to download a big file and `IProgress<float>` to send percentages to the main thread, here is my code:

```
Task.Run(() => 
{ 
   while (true) 
   { //SA??? 

      int actualBytes = 0; 
      try 
      { 
         cnt++; 
         bool q = strm.CanRead; 

         actualBytes = strm.Read(barr, 0, arrSize); 
      } 
      catch (Exception e) 
      { 
         MessageBox.Show(e.Message); 
      } 

      if (actualBytes <= 0) 
      break; 

      fs.Write(barr, 0, actualBytes); 
      bytesCounter += actualBytes; 
      double percent = 0d; 
      if (fileLength > 0) 
      percent = 
         100.0d * bytesCounter / 
         (preloadedLength + fileLength); 


      progress.Report((float)percent); 

   } 

progress.Report(-1); 
});
```

And when internet connection is good all works fine, but when the internet connection closes for a second an exception is not triggering.  Debugging this code with f5 and f10, on the line with `strm.Read` just throws me out from the task code showing nothing.  What am I doing wrong and how can I correctly continue downloading the file after losing my internet connection?

Comment: You don't need all that to download. Assuming you use HttpClient, ReadAsStreamAsync will return a stream. Stream.CopyToAsync will copy it to another stream (eg a file) without blocking. [Check this article](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/efficiently-streaming-large-http-responses-with-httpclient) Anyway, losing connectivity for a second should *NOT* throw any exceptions. Otherwise you wouldn't be able to use Wi-FI for anything. *The OS* will try to reconnect. Only if that times out will you get an error

Comment: If you want to know the connectivity status, use `System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();`

Comment: In any case, you'll always has such issues eg with Wi-FI. Your code should be able to timeout if the wait is too long and retry the operation. You should probably keep track of how many bytes are downloaded and try to download *after* that position by specifying the appropriate headers

Comment: Just saw that you use `MessageBox.Show` *inside* Task.Run. You can't modify the UI from another thread or task. This will result in an unhandled exception. If you want to report progress, even errors, use the `IProgress< T>` interface and/or a logger

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `MessageBox.Show` doesn't need to run on the UI thread.  It creates its own message loop in the current thread, turning that thread into the UI thread for that particular message box.  It's not accessing a UI control from a different thread than the one it was created on, so there would be no cross thread exceptions.  If it create its own message loop that would cause a *different* set of problems (i.e. if you created new controls and tried to use them without an existing message loop then they'd be sending message that would never fire, causing...problems).